# How to solve the characteristic equations $\frac{dx_1}{x_1} = \frac{dx_2}{x_2} = \frac{dx_3}{x_3}= \frac{dV}{2V}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

My question is an extension of my old question: [How to solve the characteristic equations $\frac{dx_1}{x_1} = \frac{dx_2}{x_2} = \frac{dV}{2V}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687200/how-to-solve-the-characteristic-equations-fracdx-1x-1-fracdx-2x-2)

So, follow the suggested solution, I would get

Given the PDE: 
$$x_1\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1}+ x_2\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2} + x_3\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_3} = 2V,$$ 
where $V = V(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic  ODEs are: 
$$\frac{dx_1}{x_1} = \frac{dx_2}{x_2} = \frac{dx_3}{x_3} = \frac{dV}{2V}.$$

1st, $dx_1/x_1 = dV/2V$ leads to 
$$C_0 = \frac{V}{x_1^2}$$

2nd, $dx_2/x_2 = dV/2V$ leads to 
$$C_1 = \frac{V}{x_2^2}$$

3rd, $dx_3/x_3 = dV/2V$ leads to 
$$C_2 = \frac{V}{x_3^2}$$

4th, $dx_1/x_1 = dx_2/x_2$ leads to 
$$\frac{x_2}{x_1} = \alpha_1.$$

5th, $dx_2/x_2 = dx_3/x_3$ leads to 
$$\frac{x_3}{x_2} = \alpha_2.$$

6th, $dx_1/x_1 = dx_3/x_3$ leads to 
$$\frac{x_3}{x_1} = \alpha_3.$$

So the general solution can be written as

$$C_0=F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)\, \Rightarrow\, \frac{V}{x_1^2} = F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \, \Rightarrow \, V(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2 F(\alpha_1, \alpha_2)$$

I am not sure if my general solution $V$ is correct. My questions really is:

> There are many combinations, $C_0, \ldots, C_2$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_3$. How to write down a general solution? or are there many general solutions?

For higher dimension, I am confused about it. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Not sure why -2?   I show my effort.  Is my question not clear?

Comment: Did you intend to imply that your general solution is $V(x)=x_1^2F(\frac{x_2}{x_1},\frac{x_3}{x_2})$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes!. however, there are different combinations, such as $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$, $(\alpha_2, \alpha_3)$..also, $x^2_1$ can be replaced by $x^2_2$ or $x^2_3$.

Comment: Yes, but they are all equivalent as long as no variable is zero. $x_2^2=x_1^2α_1^2$, $α_3=α_1α_2$ etc.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So you mean it is enough for me to pick one of them?

Comment: Yes. The form of the initial condition, when given, might single out one that is most suitable.